# Azure Cmdlets (Add-AzureCertificate) Failing with HTTP Status Code : NotFound

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

From powershell, I am trying to add certificate to a service that was already created and I am running into the following error

> Add-AzureCertificate : HTTP Status Code: NotFound - HTTP Error
>   Message:
>   https://management.core.windows.net/97d3cd24-78a1-44ba-aea4-0dd7c733cb56/services/hostedservices/XXXX
>   /certificates does not exist.
>
> Operation ID:
>   dc1eabcef0c74861853fe53ed047f674 At
>   +                 Add-AzureCertificate <<<<  -ServiceName $servicename -CertToDeploy $CertificatePath -Password $Password
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureCertificate], CommunicationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.Certificates.AddAzureCertificate

This works fine on one subscription (say subscription A) but fails on each service in the subscription (say subscription B)

Wondering what this error actually means? I do see a folder by the name 'Certificates' under the service to which I am trying to add the certificate

I have also imported the appropriate publish settings of subscription A & B and I don't do anything different on subscription A to make it work!

Could you please help me on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correct, It might be due subscription context. to In case of multiple Subscription, its necessary to change default context of Subscription in your power-shell for which you are trying to perform operation .

### Example  : Two  : subscriptionA  and subscriptionB

1. Execute : Get-AzureSubscription
2. Make sure you see all (2 in this case) subscriptions
3. Use 'Select-AzureSubscription command to select context to the subscription where you want to perform operation .
4. Use Set-AzureSubscription to set right context 
   PS C:> Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName SubscriptionA -CurrentStorageAccount  < YourStorageaccountName>
5. Run this to Verify that right Subscription is set  : PS C:> Get-AzureSubscription -Current
6. Perform your operation .
7. Now go back to step 3 with SubscrptionB and continue.

-----------------This Might help to change the context ------------

Select-AzureSubscription

```
PS C:\> Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName SubscriptionA

PS C:\>
```

Set-AzureSubscription

```
PS C:\> Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName SubscriptionA -CurrentStorageAccount <YourStorageaccountName>

PS C:\>
```

Remove-AzureSubscription

```
PS C:\> Remove-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName SubscriptionA -Force
    WARNING: The default subscription is being removed. Use Select-Subscription <subscriptionName> to select a new default subscription.
    WARNING: The current subscription is being removed. Use Select-Subscription <subscriptionName> to select a new current subscription.
```

---

Comment: Thanks Abhishek! This worked. However I think the "Set-AzureSubscription" is not required as the certificate is not uploaded to a blob in the storage account specified with the -CurrentStorageAccount parameter